# Redirect all traffic from one folder to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a blog hosted at say domain.com/site but have built a new website.  I want to redirect all traffic from domain.com/site/*anything* to domain.com/home/ so that any traffic going to any page or file on the old site gets redirected to the new homepage.

I am unsure what code to place in the .htaccess file and also where on the server to place it

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
Redirect 301 {old path} http://domain.com/{new path}
```

you can place that at the root of your website, with the old path and Apache will redirect to the new site.

In your case:

```
Redirect 301 /site/anything http://domain.com/home
```

Comment: sorry.  the anything isn't actually a directory it should have had * around it.

so in that case the code would be

REDIRECT 301 /site http://domain.com/home and this will redirect for example domain.com/site/apple, /site/banana etc all to domain.com/home?

Comment: Something like `RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/.*$ http://domain.com/home` should do it for you.